# Using Knockout AfterRender, but on the child (iterating) element not the parent

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi guys I have a scenario, where I'm running a foreach, and that's using a template. The after Render always calls the Object that contains the collection. I'd rather it called the iterating element, so that I can set properties on it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `afterRender` callback actually takes in two parameters, the first is the parent object and the second is the child.  Just make your callback take in a second parameter and you should be good to go.